# What is the best practice for working with arrays of varying size in python/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

Normally how you would use numpy is to create an empty array and add values in as they come. I am working on a script where I iterate over some data, but I don't know how large each element I need to add is going to be, so I'm not able to preallocate memory. What is the best practice for dealing with such a situation? I can append the data to a object type array, but that is slow. Is there a better way to handle this?

Example:

```
# data is shape (100,256,256)
results_hist = np.zeros((0,0), dtype=object)
for i in data:
    results = doSomething(i) # varying size
    results_hist = np.append(results_hist,results)
```

Is this the best practice?

Comment: use a `list` then create a `np.array` out of it at the end

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Sorry I wasn't clear, I mean to say you would normally allocate memory with an empty array and fill in the values as you get them. But yes you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologize, sorry I was too hasty!  I read the question too fast, which lead me to interpret the code that you show as an implementation of what you were describing in the beginning of the question.  But after reading it again, it is clear that your "normally" case refers to preallocating an array and filling in the values. @juanpa.arrivillaga's concise statement is the way to go when you don't know the size in advance.